# Landscape ltablex error with \pagebreak

Tags: tables, tabularx, landscape

For my thesis I'm trying to create a quite complex landscape, multipage table. I realise there are loads of questions about this on SE so far, but none of the solutions have worked for me and I don't know why. Granted, this table is a bit Frankenstein at this point as it's been repurposed from previous documents.

I think I've arrived at using `ltablex` from what I've been reading as it supports the custom columns I specified, which I don't think worked with `longtable` when I tried - though I didn't persist for long.

Currently my table compiles perfectly fine, until I put a pagebreak in it. I'm then thrown `\multispan ->\omit \@multispan` error.

I've tried `\noalign{\break}` which I saw in other solutions and it seemingly has no effect on the table. What/where am I missing/going wrong?

**MWE** (I've included some aesthetic stuff such as the headers as it's relevant to the scaling of the table)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}

\keepXColumns
\newcommand\tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut
\usepackage{subcaption}

% New column type for tabular
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\ttfamily\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\ttfamily\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  %% Adds headers and footers.
\headsep 25pt
\headheight 20pt
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{670pt}

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header and footer
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage\ }% Custom footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}
\lhead{\textsf{Chapter II}}
\rhead{\textsf{Materials \& Methodology}}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\scriptsize
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified, font=footnotesize}
\caption[Special Primer Sequences]{Primers for specialist purposes, including cloning and recombineering. Restriction sites are shown in \textbf{bold}. Annealing temperatures shown in [ ] are specific to NEB's Q5 Polymerase. Where appropriate, overlap homology is shown \underline{underlined}. F: Forward Primer, R: Reverse Primer, bp - Base Pair.}
\label{specprimers}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c  c  L c  c }

Primer Name  & Function/Target  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sequence (5' $\rightarrow$ 3')} & Tm ($^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$) & Length (bp)\\[0.5ex]
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Classical Cloning}\tstrut\bstrut\\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut
PVCpnf13-NdeI\_F & \multirow{3}{*}{\emph{pnf} Tail Fibre} & GAGTTA\textbf{CATATG}AACGAAACTCGTTATAATGC & [67] & \multirow{3}{*}{1548} \\
PVCpnf13-BamHI\_R & & TTTTCA\textbf{GGATCC}TTAAAGCTTTATGATGAAAGC & [67] &  \\
PVCpnf13-KpnI\_R & & TTTTCA\textbf{GGTACC}AAAAGCTTTATGATGAAAGC & [67] & \\[0.5ex]

PVClumt13-NdeI\_F & \multirow{3}{*}{\emph{lumt} Tail Fibre} & GCCGGA\textbf{CATATG}GACAACAAAAATAAC & [67] & \multirow{3}{*}{675} \\
PVClumt13-BamHI\_R & & TTACTT\textbf{GGATCC}TTACACAACCTTAATCATATAG & [67] &  \\
PVClumt13-KpnI\_R & & TTACTT\textbf{GGTACC}AACACAACCTTAATCATATAG & [67] & \\[0.5ex]

PVCpnf11-NdeI\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{\emph{pnf} Baseplate} & ACAGGT\textbf{CATATG}GAATTAAATGAGTTAACTAACAAATT & [67] & \multirow{2}{*}{2208} \\
PVCpnf11-BamHI\_R & & AGTGCA\textbf{GGATCC}TTACTCATAGTCATTTCCTC & [67] &  \\[0.5ex]
\hline

\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Gibson Assembly}\tstrut\bstrut \\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut

pBAD30frag\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & \underline{ATGTAATTAATTCAACCATCACGGAGAGTTTATCAA}CGCCGTAGCGCCGATGGTAGTGTGGGGTCTCCCC & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{4791} \\
pBAD30frag\_R & & \underline{CTTGTAGACATAAAAGCCCCTTTTTAGACAAAAAA}TAGCCCAAAAAAACGGGTATGGAGAAACAGTAGAG & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag1\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & CTCTACTGTTTCTCCATACCCGTTTTTTTGGGCTATTTTTTGTCTAAAAAGGGGCTTTTATGTCTACAAG & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag1\_R & & GTGTCAGTATTTGATTTTCCATTCATCGTCACCTTTCATTGGGTAAGATTAATTTTTGCGCCTTTGATTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag2\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & AAATCAAAGGCGCAAAAATTAATCTTACCCAATGAAAGGTGACGATGAATGGAAAATCAAATACTGACAC & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag2\_R & & TCTTGTACAGTTGCATTATAACGAGTTTCGTTCATGATTAACTCCAGAAAACATATTTAATTCAACATCA & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag3\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & TGATGTTGAATTAAATATGTTTTCTGGAGTTAATCATGAACGAAACTCGTTATAATGCAACTGTACAAGA & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag3\_R & & TTATTGACATCAATAATAGTTTGCGTGTTTAACATAAAAAACCTCTCTTAAATTATATCGTGATAACTTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag4\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & AAAGTTATCACGATATAATTTAAGAGAGGTTTTTTATGTTAAACACGCAAACTATTATTGATGTCAATAA & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag4\_R & & TTATTGACATCAATAATAGTTTGCGTGTTTAACATAAAAAACCTCTCTTAAATTATATCGTGATAACTTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]
\pagebreak
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Recombineering Primers}\tstrut\bstrut\\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut
rpoA F & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3.5cm}{\centering Blah}} & GCGTATTAAAGTTCAGCGTG & [72] & 528 \\
rpoA500 R & & TGAAGCCAGTACGTCTTTG & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

EDIT, **Second MWE**

I've followed David's advice and removed the `table` environment, but as I mentioned in the comments, I still have the same error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}

\keepXColumns
\newcommand\tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut
\usepackage{subcaption}

% New column type for tabular
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\ttfamily\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\ttfamily\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  %% Adds headers and footers.
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\headsep 25pt
\headheight 20pt
%\footskip  20pt
%\footheight 15pt
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{670pt}

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header and footer
 % \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage\ }% Custom footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}
\lhead{\textsf{Chapter II}}
\rhead{\textsf{Materials \& Methodology}}
\begin{landscape}
\scriptsize
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified, font=footnotesize}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c  c  L c  c }
\caption[Special Primer Sequences]{Primers for specialist purposes, including cloning and recombineering. Restriction sites are shown in \textbf{bold}. Annealing temperatures shown in [ ] are specific to NEB's Q5 Polymerase. Where appropriate, overlap homology is shown \underline{underlined}. F: Forward Primer, R: Reverse Primer, bp - Base Pair.}
\label{specprimers}\\

Primer Name  & Function/Target  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sequence (5' $\rightarrow$ 3')} & Tm ($^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$) & Length (bp)\\[0.5ex]
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Classical Cloning}\tstrut\bstrut\\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut
PVCpnf13-NdeI\_F & \multirow{3}{*}{\emph{pnf} Tail Fibre} & GAGTTA\textbf{CATATG}AACGAAACTCGTTATAATGC & [67] & \multirow{3}{*}{1548} \\
PVCpnf13-BamHI\_R & & TTTTCA\textbf{GGATCC}TTAAAGCTTTATGATGAAAGC & [67] &  \\
PVCpnf13-KpnI\_R & & TTTTCA\textbf{GGTACC}AAAAGCTTTATGATGAAAGC & [67] & \\[0.5ex]

PVClumt13-NdeI\_F & \multirow{3}{*}{\emph{lumt} Tail Fibre} & GCCGGA\textbf{CATATG}GACAACAAAAATAAC & [67] & \multirow{3}{*}{675} \\
PVClumt13-BamHI\_R & & TTACTT\textbf{GGATCC}TTACACAACCTTAATCATATAG & [67] &  \\
PVClumt13-KpnI\_R & & TTACTT\textbf{GGTACC}AACACAACCTTAATCATATAG & [67] & \\[0.5ex]

PVCpnf11-NdeI\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{\emph{pnf} Baseplate} & ACAGGT\textbf{CATATG}GAATTAAATGAGTTAACTAACAAATT & [67] & \multirow{2}{*}{2208} \\
PVCpnf11-BamHI\_R & & AGTGCA\textbf{GGATCC}TTACTCATAGTCATTTCCTC & [67] &  \\[0.5ex]
\hline

\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Gibson Assembly}\tstrut\bstrut \\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut

pBAD30frag\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & \underline{ATGTAATTAATTCAACCATCACGGAGAGTTTATCAA}CGCCGTAGCGCCGATGGTAGTGTGGGGTCTCCCC & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{4791} \\
pBAD30frag\_R & & \underline{CTTGTAGACATAAAAGCCCCTTTTTAGACAAAAAA}TAGCCCAAAAAAACGGGTATGGAGAAACAGTAGAG & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag1\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & CTCTACTGTTTCTCCATACCCGTTTTTTTGGGCTATTTTTTGTCTAAAAAGGGGCTTTTATGTCTACAAG & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag1\_R & & GTGTCAGTATTTGATTTTCCATTCATCGTCACCTTTCATTGGGTAAGATTAATTTTTGCGCCTTTGATTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag2\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & AAATCAAAGGCGCAAAAATTAATCTTACCCAATGAAAGGTGACGATGAATGGAAAATCAAATACTGACAC & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag2\_R & & TCTTGTACAGTTGCATTATAACGAGTTTCGTTCATGATTAACTCCAGAAAACATATTTAATTCAACATCA & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag3\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & TGATGTTGAATTAAATATGTTTTCTGGAGTTAATCATGAACGAAACTCGTTATAATGCAACTGTACAAGA & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag3\_R & & TTATTGACATCAATAATAGTTTGCGTGTTTAACATAAAAAACCTCTCTTAAATTATATCGTGATAACTTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag4\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & AAAGTTATCACGATATAATTTAAGAGAGGTTTTTTATGTTAAACACGCAAACTATTATTGATGTCAATAA & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag4\_R & & TTATTGACATCAATAATAGTTTGCGTGTTTAACATAAAAAACCTCTCTTAAATTATATCGTGATAACTTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]
\pagebreak

\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Recombineering Primers}\tstrut\bstrut\\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut
rpoA F & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3.5cm}{\centering Blah}} & GCGTATTAAAGTTCAGCGTG & [72] & 528 \\
rpoA500 R & & TGAAGCCAGTACGTCTTTG & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can not have a multipage table inside `table` as that is an unbreakable box

Comment: for any document being written by hand I would always use longtable rather than tabularx/ltablex  the time taken to choose suitable column widths is nothing compared to the time taken to write the document. It is different in automated typesetting of database dumps where you want the system to choose some sensible layout automatically.

Comment: I had thought that to be at least part of the problem from reading other threads  but I've tested the above code without the table environment and I still get through same error without it, so it seems that can only be part of the puzzle?

Comment: If you want help with an error it's usually best to post the code that makes the error rather than the version without, I couldn't guess where you had put `\pagebreak` to get that error (it has to be at the start of a row otherwise you get that error)

Comment: Ah sorry, edited. I must have copied and pasted the wrong version (the version that does compile without pagebreak)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update for added MWE**

This is really a bug in `ltablex` (as I say in comments, I'd use `longtable` directly myself, `tabularx` doesn't add a lot here) but `ltablex` switches the environment from being a `tabularx` or a `longtable` according to some heuristics, you need the longtable version of `\newpage` always otherwise it will give an error if used before `\hline` (and other places) but teh package doesn't take care of that. The easiest way is to force the `\pagebreak` into a safe place (and then disable longtable's attempt to get to use the same `\noalign` trick that you just used)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}

\keepXColumns
\newcommand\tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut
\usepackage{subcaption}

% New column type for tabular
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\ttfamily\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\ttfamily\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  %% Adds headers and footers.
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\headsep 25pt
\headheight 20pt
%\footskip  20pt
%\footheight 15pt
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{670pt}

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header and footer
 % \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage\ }% Custom footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}
\lhead{\textsf{Chapter II}}
\rhead{\textsf{Materials \& Methodology}}
\begin{landscape}
\scriptsize
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified, font=footnotesize}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c  c  L c  c }
\caption[Special Primer Sequences]{Primers for specialist purposes, including cloning and recombineering. Restriction sites are shown in \textbf{bold}. Annealing temperatures shown in [ ] are specific to NEB's Q5 Polymerase. Where appropriate, overlap homology is shown \underline{underlined}. F: Forward Primer, R: Reverse Primer, bp - Base Pair.}
\label{specprimers}\\

Primer Name  & Function/Target  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sequence (5' $\rightarrow$ 3')} & Tm ($^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$) & Length (bp)\\[0.5ex]
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Classical Cloning}\tstrut\bstrut\\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut
PVCpnf13-NdeI\_F & \multirow{3}{*}{\emph{pnf} Tail Fibre} & GAGTTA\textbf{CATATG}AACGAAACTCGTTATAATGC & [67] & \multirow{3}{*}{1548} \\
PVCpnf13-BamHI\_R & & TTTTCA\textbf{GGATCC}TTAAAGCTTTATGATGAAAGC & [67] &  \\
PVCpnf13-KpnI\_R & & TTTTCA\textbf{GGTACC}AAAAGCTTTATGATGAAAGC & [67] & \\[0.5ex]

PVClumt13-NdeI\_F & \multirow{3}{*}{\emph{lumt} Tail Fibre} & GCCGGA\textbf{CATATG}GACAACAAAAATAAC & [67] & \multirow{3}{*}{675} \\
PVClumt13-BamHI\_R & & TTACTT\textbf{GGATCC}TTACACAACCTTAATCATATAG & [67] &  \\
PVClumt13-KpnI\_R & & TTACTT\textbf{GGTACC}AACACAACCTTAATCATATAG & [67] & \\[0.5ex]

PVCpnf11-NdeI\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{\emph{pnf} Baseplate} & ACAGGT\textbf{CATATG}GAATTAAATGAGTTAACTAACAAATT & [67] & \multirow{2}{*}{2208} \\
PVCpnf11-BamHI\_R & & AGTGCA\textbf{GGATCC}TTACTCATAGTCATTTCCTC & [67] &  \\[0.5ex]
\hline

\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Gibson Assembly}\tstrut\bstrut \\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut

pBAD30frag\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & \underline{ATGTAATTAATTCAACCATCACGGAGAGTTTATCAA}CGCCGTAGCGCCGATGGTAGTGTGGGGTCTCCCC & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{4791} \\
pBAD30frag\_R & & \underline{CTTGTAGACATAAAAGCCCCTTTTTAGACAAAAAA}TAGCCCAAAAAAACGGGTATGGAGAAACAGTAGAG & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag1\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & CTCTACTGTTTCTCCATACCCGTTTTTTTGGGCTATTTTTTGTCTAAAAAGGGGCTTTTATGTCTACAAG & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag1\_R & & GTGTCAGTATTTGATTTTCCATTCATCGTCACCTTTCATTGGGTAAGATTAATTTTTGCGCCTTTGATTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag2\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & AAATCAAAGGCGCAAAAATTAATCTTACCCAATGAAAGGTGACGATGAATGGAAAATCAAATACTGACAC & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag2\_R & & TCTTGTACAGTTGCATTATAACGAGTTTCGTTCATGATTAACTCCAGAAAACATATTTAATTCAACATCA & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag3\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & TGATGTTGAATTAAATATGTTTTCTGGAGTTAATCATGAACGAAACTCGTTATAATGCAACTGTACAAGA & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag3\_R & & TTATTGACATCAATAATAGTTTGCGTGTTTAACATAAAAAACCTCTCTTAAATTATATCGTGATAACTTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag4\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & AAAGTTATCACGATATAATTTAAGAGAGGTTTTTTATGTTAAACACGCAAACTATTATTGATGTCAATAA & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag4\_R & & TTATTGACATCAATAATAGTTTGCGTGTTTAACATAAAAAACCTCTCTTAAATTATATCGTGATAACTTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]
\noalign{\let\noalign\relax\pagebreak}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Recombineering Primers}\tstrut\bstrut\\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut
rpoA F & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3.5cm}{\centering Blah}} & GCGTATTAAAGTTCAGCGTG & [72] & 528 \\
rpoA500 R & & TGAAGCCAGTACGTCTTTG & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

You say `\pagebreak` gave an error, but you did not say where you put it, I placed it after a random `\\` and it forces a 2 column table (after I removed the `table` environment which would stop the page breaking (but not make `\pagebreak` give the error you showed)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}

\keepXColumns
\newcommand\tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut
\usepackage{subcaption}

% New column type for tabular
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\ttfamily\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\ttfamily\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  %% Adds headers and footers.
\headsep 25pt
\headheight 20pt
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{670pt}

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header and footer
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage\ }% Custom footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}
\lhead{\textsf{Chapter II}}
\rhead{\textsf{Materials \& Methodology}}
\begin{landscape}

\scriptsize
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified, font=footnotesize}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c  c  L c  c }
\caption[Special Primer Sequences]{Primers for specialist purposes, including cloning and recombineering. Restriction sites are shown in \textbf{bold}. Annealing temperatures shown in [ ] are specific to NEB's Q5 Polymerase. Where appropriate, overlap homology is shown \underline{underlined}. F: Forward Primer, R: Reverse Primer, bp - Base Pair.}
\label{specprimers}\\
Primer Name  & Function/Target  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sequence (5' $\rightarrow$ 3')} & Tm ($^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$) & Length (bp)\\[0.5ex]
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Classical Cloning}\tstrut\bstrut\\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut
PVCpnf13-NdeI\_F & \multirow{3}{*}{\emph{pnf} Tail Fibre} & GAGTTA\textbf{CATATG}AACGAAACTCGTTATAATGC & [67] & \multirow{3}{*}{1548} \\\pagebreak
PVCpnf13-BamHI\_R & & TTTTCA\textbf{GGATCC}TTAAAGCTTTATGATGAAAGC & [67] &  \\
PVCpnf13-KpnI\_R & & TTTTCA\textbf{GGTACC}AAAAGCTTTATGATGAAAGC & [67] & \\[0.5ex]

PVClumt13-NdeI\_F & \multirow{3}{*}{\emph{lumt} Tail Fibre} & GCCGGA\textbf{CATATG}GACAACAAAAATAAC & [67] & \multirow{3}{*}{675} \\
PVClumt13-BamHI\_R & & TTACTT\textbf{GGATCC}TTACACAACCTTAATCATATAG & [67] &  \\
PVClumt13-KpnI\_R & & TTACTT\textbf{GGTACC}AACACAACCTTAATCATATAG & [67] & \\[0.5ex]

PVCpnf11-NdeI\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{\emph{pnf} Baseplate} & ACAGGT\textbf{CATATG}GAATTAAATGAGTTAACTAACAAATT & [67] & \multirow{2}{*}{2208} \\
PVCpnf11-BamHI\_R & & AGTGCA\textbf{GGATCC}TTACTCATAGTCATTTCCTC & [67] &  \\[0.5ex]
\hline

\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Gibson Assembly}\tstrut\bstrut \\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut

pBAD30frag\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & \underline{ATGTAATTAATTCAACCATCACGGAGAGTTTATCAA}CGCCGTAGCGCCGATGGTAGTGTGGGGTCTCCCC & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{4791} \\
pBAD30frag\_R & & \underline{CTTGTAGACATAAAAGCCCCTTTTTAGACAAAAAA}TAGCCCAAAAAAACGGGTATGGAGAAACAGTAGAG & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag1\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & CTCTACTGTTTCTCCATACCCGTTTTTTTGGGCTATTTTTTGTCTAAAAAGGGGCTTTTATGTCTACAAG & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag1\_R & & GTGTCAGTATTTGATTTTCCATTCATCGTCACCTTTCATTGGGTAAGATTAATTTTTGCGCCTTTGATTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag2\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & AAATCAAAGGCGCAAAAATTAATCTTACCCAATGAAAGGTGACGATGAATGGAAAATCAAATACTGACAC & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag2\_R & & TCTTGTACAGTTGCATTATAACGAGTTTCGTTCATGATTAACTCCAGAAAACATATTTAATTCAACATCA & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag3\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & TGATGTTGAATTAAATATGTTTTCTGGAGTTAATCATGAACGAAACTCGTTATAATGCAACTGTACAAGA & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag3\_R & & TTATTGACATCAATAATAGTTTGCGTGTTTAACATAAAAAACCTCTCTTAAATTATATCGTGATAACTTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

PNFfrag4\_F & \multirow{2}{*}{pBAD30} & AAAGTTATCACGATATAATTTAAGAGAGGTTTTTTATGTTAAACACGCAAACTATTATTGATGTCAATAA & [72] & \multirow{2}{*}{7251} \\
PNFfrag4\_R & & TTATTGACATCAATAATAGTTTGCGTGTTTAACATAAAAAACCTCTCTTAAATTATATCGTGATAACTTT & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]
\hline

\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\centering Recombineering Primers}\tstrut\bstrut\\[0.5ex]
\hline\tstrut\bstrut
rpoA F & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3.5cm}{\centering Blah}} & GCGTATTAAAGTTCAGCGTG & [72] & 528 \\
rpoA500 R & & TGAAGCCAGTACGTCTTTG & [72] &  \\[0.5ex]

\end{tabularx}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can indeed copy your code exactly and get a table that breaks at the point you inserted a pagebreak, I can't however seem to make it break correctly elsewhere, namely just before the last `\multicolumn{}` line. It seems the table is quite happy to break at any of the table entries, even if they end in a merged row, but unable to be broken before or after the multicolumn lines as far as I can tell

Comment: @JoeHealey answer updated

Comment: Perfect thank you! I'll bear in mind the arguments for longtable and perhaps persist with it a little longer than I did, but for now `\noalign{\let\noalign\relax\pagebreak}` does exactly what I need.